# How to return the sum of returned values in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

How do I return the sum of the "Update time (secs):" and "Gups:" to find the total values of each?

I appreciate any help!

Code:

```
root@:~/gups# mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 2 gups_vanilla 20 1000 1024
Number of procs: 1
Vector size: 1048576
Max datums during comm: 0
Max datums after comm: 1024
Excess datums (frac): 0 (0)
Bad locality count: 0
Update time (secs):     0.003
Gups:  0.301295
Number of procs: 1
Vector size: 1048576
Max datums during comm: 0
Max datums after comm: 1024
Excess datums (frac): 0 (0)
Bad locality count: 0
Update time (secs):     0.004
Gups:  0.233969
root@:~/gups# mpirun --allow-run-as-root -np 2 gups_vanilla 20 1000 1024 | awk -F: '$1 == "Gups"{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
0.429367
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having your output I wasn't able to test this but you should be able to use awk:

```
<command> | awk -F: '$1 == "Gups"{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

`-F:` tells awk to use `:` as a field separator, then for any record where the first field equals `Gups` the second field will be added to the `sum` variable.  After awk is done reading all records it will print `sum`

Comment: Thank you for the response! This runs great and returns a sum. Unfortunately, the sum appears to be off.

Comment: @SomeWiseGuy: You haven't updated your question with the required information.

Comment: Just did, let me know if you need any more information

Comment: @SomeWiseGuy no as we have said please don't post screenshots.  Copy and paste the actual text.

Comment: There is also no reason to `grep Gups` that is what `$1 == "Gups"` does in the awk program